# Matching multiple vectors in R

Tags: r

Is there a way/alternative to `match()` that enables multiple vectors to be matched up?  To illustrate:

```
df1 = data.frame(c1=letters[1:10], c2=1:10, c4=10:1)
df2 = data.frame(c1=c('a','b','c','x'), c2=c(1,2,4,4))
```

If we want to attach the `df1$c4` data to appropriate rows of `df2` we can use `match()` like so

```
df1$c3 = paste(df1$c1, df1$c2)
df2$c3 = paste(df2$c1, df2$c2)
df2$c4 = df1$c4[match(df2$c3, df1$c3)]
```

but this seems a bit long-winded.  Does anyone know a more elegant technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge()` function should be what you're looking for. Ex:

```
> merge(df1,df2,all.x=T)
   c1 c2 c4
1   a  1 10
2   b  2  9
3   c  3  8
4   d  4  7
5   e  5  6
6   f  6  5
7   g  7  4
8   h  8  3
9   i  9  2
10  j 10  1
> merge(df1,df2,all.y=T)
  c1 c2 c4
1  a  1 10
2  b  2  9
3  c  4 NA
4  x  4 NA
```

Comment: Thanks David, not used merge but knew it had to be something like that

Comment: Also, using `na.locf()` in conjunction with `merge` helps when you wish to replace each NA with the most recent non-NA prior to it.